# Space between two columns in SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure where we input machines model with Model-MachineType-Serial. Everything is perfect, but if user adds a space between hyphens `-`, it should also work.

When the user passes in

```
spGetMacDetailsByName null, 'Hble-1-11979'
```

it is working fine, but when the users adds a space, it doesn't return anything

```
spGetMacDetailsByName null, 'Hble - 1-  11979'
```

On the other hand if we input

```
spGetMacDetailsByName null, 'Hble- '
```

like this it should also work.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMacDetailsByName] 
    @MachineID int = NULL,
    @Model AS nvarchar(300) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM MachineDetails 
    WHERE (MachineID = @MachineID OR @MachineID IS NULL) 
      AND ISNULL(IsShared, 0) = 1
      AND (Model = +@Model 
           OR (CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Model)) AS nvarchar) + '-' +
               CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(MachineType)) AS nvarchar)) = @Model
           OR (CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Model)) AS nvarchar) + '-' +
               CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(MachineType)) AS nvarchar) + '-' +
               CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Serial)) AS nvarchar)) = @Model
           OR @Model IS NULL)
END
```

Comment: Remove the spaces at the start of the procedure : set @Model = replace(@Model, ' ', '')

Comment: Seems like you should be normalising your design; clearly Model, Machine Type and Serial should be 3 separated columns and 3 separate parameters.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise you might end up unexpectedly getting a `NVARCHAR` with a **default length of *1* character!**

Comment: its not working kindly help

Comment: "Not working" means nothing to us, @Saif , as "not working" could mean anything.

Comment: Just have three separate parameters for `Model-MachineType-Serial` rather than passing them as an inconsistently formatted concatenated string

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: The same way you would pass the current 2 you have, but you would have 4 instead, @Saif . If you aren't familiar with how to add parameters to a procedure, and pass them, that suggests you don't understand the SQL in your own question; I would focus there first. If you don't understand the (flawed) solution you have, you aren't going to understand the solutions you get.

Comment: i want this formate `Hble-1-11979` with also spaces like this  `Hble- 1 -11979` etc.

Comment: `(Model = +@Model` Not valid syntax. `ISNULL(IsShared, 0) = 1` Over-complicated. NULL is never equal to anything, you can safely remove ISNULL. Perhaps you shouldn't allow null in that column? And stop trimming - don't encourage lazy coding for the callers of your procedure. MAKE them provide valid values.

Comment: how can i achieve this `Hble- 1 -11979` ? i need help for this, if i add space it should also work